# Stock of products during time

Tags: sql

We need to create a query in which we will have the available stock of our products during next weeks.

We have 4 kind of orders-invoices.

a) Orders from suppliers which have an estimated delivery date

b) Invoices from suppliers which are being transformed from their orders and they also have a date

c) Orders for Clients with estimated execution date

d) Invoices for clients with a date

The a,b are going to add quantities to our table

The c,d are going to remove quantities from our table

For example:

We are currently on week 27 and we know that at 12 of July (week 28) we will receive 100 pcs of product A.

Then a client already pre-ordered 50 pcs with execution date 25 of July (week 30) , so we have an order which should reduce the quantity of product A at week 30.

If we are going to receive at 2 of August 100 pcs more, then on week 31 the table should show the estimated quantity by calculating:

```
 Week27 - 0   pcs
 Week28 - 100 pcs (we will receive 100 pcs)
 Week29 - 100 pcs (nothing was sold)
 Week30 - 50  pcs (we will sell 50 pcs so the remaining quantity is 50)
 Week31 - 150 pcs (we will receive 100 pcs so the remaining quantity will be 150)
```

Comment: what have you tried? where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask].  SO is not a code writing service.  If you have a *specific* question, let us know. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty common requirement in any Warehouse Management or ERP system, they mostly do this in a similar way: Store every transaction as either a positive or negative number. then for each date, sum every transaction prior to that date.

Pseudo-code as follows, obviously implement to suit your database schema:

```
Select 
    Week, 
   (Select 
           Sum(Quantity) from 
           Transactions 
            where date < Weeks.EndDate) as ClosingBalance

from Weeks
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution which I think can work:

Firstly I created a View in our database named z_531 in which we collect all the nessecare rows with the product information and also Date etc.

Then I tried to make a cumulative sum in a query:

`SELECT    Date,Product,[Quantity A],[Date of Import export], [Week of import export], [Year of import export],Client,
                          (SELECT     SUM([Quantity A]) AS Expr1
                            FROM          dbo.z_531 AS b
                            WHERE      ([Wekk of Import Export] <= dbo.z_531.[Week of Import Export]) and ([Product] = dbo.z_531.[Product])) AS [Stock quantity]

FROM         dbo.z_531

ORDER BY [Product], [Date of Import Export]`

By adding in my sum Product = dbo.z_531.[Product] I have seperated sums per product and also by week.

Eventhough I think its not the quickest way to do it !